# Is there a .htaccess domain variable that excludes the subdomain portion?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a `.htaccess` variable I can use which excludes the subdomain?

For example, if the domain is `www.example.com`, how can I use `example.com` in my `.htaccess` file?

I need to use a variable. I can't hard code `example.com`.

It's a `RewriteRule` in a `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.%{DOMAIN_WITHOUT_SUBDOMAIN}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOMAIN_WITHOUT_SUBDOMAIN}/app/controllers/mobile/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're attempting to achieve?  What kind of configuration directive in the htaccess file are you looking to use this in?

Comment: Hi Shane. I have a very complex domain structure I use for about 150 websites. When people go to subdomain.some-domain.com I need to redirect them to some-domain.com/script.php. The problem is I don't know which domain they are using, so I need to use a server variable to redirect subdomain.some-domain.com to some-domain.com. Basically I just need a server variable which excludes the subdomain portion.

Comment: Are you looking to use it in a `RewriteRule`?  Or your PHP code?  What exactly you'll be doing to redirect is relevant to how this can be accomplished.

Comment: Hi Shane. It's a RewriteRule in a htaccess file. For example RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.%{DOMAIN_WITHOUT_SUBDOMAIN}$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{DOMAIN_WITHOUT_SUBDOMAIN}/app/controllers/mobile/index.php [L] PS Sorry for crappy formatting, the two spaces for a new line thing doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've pretty much got it - the trick is that you can use matches from the `RewriteCond` in your `RewriteRule`.

So, to redirect a request to `http://subdomain.example.com/something` to `http://example.com/script.php`:

```
# We'll capture the last two period-separated sections
# (as well as ensure that at least 3 sections were in the requested hostname)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.([^\.]\.[^\.])$
# Now we can use that captured section (the last two parts of the name) with %1:
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%1/script.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Minor point, no need to backslash-escape literal dots in the regex character class.